# Extend a class to make it castable

Tags: c#, xna

I want to extend a class(Vector2) to make it castable to a Point.
How do i do that?

Parts of the problem:

1. Extend a class
2. Make a class castable to another class

In the end i want to be able to do this:

```
Vector2 foo = new Vector2(5.2f);  // X = 5.2f Y = 5.2F
Point red = new Point(2,2);  // X = 2 Y = 2
red = foo;  // I know that you can make classes convert themselves automatically... somehow?
// Now red.X = 5 red.Y = 5
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do that.

[`Vector2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.aspx) is a [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ah19swz4.aspx), not a [`class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0b0thckt.aspx). And as you know it's impossible to derive from [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ah19swz4.aspx) because structs allocate fixed size on stack. So polymorphism is impossible because derived [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ah19swz4.aspx) would have different size.

As a workaround you can create [*extension method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) `ToPoint` that will return instance of struct [`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.point.aspx):

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static void ToPoint(this Vector2 vector) {
        return new Point((int)vector.X, (int)vector.Y);
    }
}

//Usage:
Vector2 foo = new Vector2(5.2f);//X = 5.2f Y = 5.2F
Point red = foo.ToPoint();
```

**Note:** This way is more intuitive than implicitly casting vector to point because vector is not a point. Implicit cast does not make any sense between those types. Actually, there are very few cases when implicit casting is really useful.

Comment: This is exactly what I use in my XNA projects.

Comment: @user1306322 Yes, it's better like this. If in future `Point` will change to another structure, you would not need to modify whole project and refactor all the `new Point(...)` occurrences. Also I find this more readable.